# Password verification in jquery not working

Tags: jquery

My problem is that I’m trying to make a simple validation for the password, I see it all correct but I’m mistaking somewhere because doesn't work, always return error even when I write the same passwords. I hope you can help me find what I’m doing wrong.

Here is the code of my inputs.

```
<form id="form2" name="form2">
    <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
    <input id="nombre"type="text" class="text" size="20" name="nombre">

    <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
    <input id="password1" type="text" class="text" size="20" name="usuario">

    <label for="contrasena">Contraseña</label>
    <input id="password1" type="password" class="text" size="20" name="contrasena">

    <label for="confirmar">Confirmar contraseña</label>
    <input id="password2" type="password" class="text" size="20" name="confirmar">

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class= "text" size="20" name="email">

    <div>
        <input type="submit" class="boton1" value="Regístrate" size="56">
    </div>
```

And here are my validations and my jquery ajax call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.boton1').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var name = $('#nombre').val();
        var password1 = $('#password1').val();
        var password2 = $('#password2').val();
        var errors = '';

        if(name.length < 5 || name == '') {
            errors += '<p>error1</p>'; 
        } else if( password1 != password2 ) {
            errors += '<p>error2</p>'; 
        }

        if(errors != '') {
            $("#login_error").show();       
            $.fancybox.resize();

            //$("#login_succes").hide();
        } else {
            var datos = $('#form2').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:'Usuario.php',
                data: datos,
                type:'POST',
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $('#seccion_registro').html('<div id="carga" style="margin:0 auto;width:auto;background-position:center center;"></div>');
                },
                success: function(){
                    $('#seccion_registro').html('<p class="text_enhorabuena">Enhorabuena, has sido registrado!</p>');
                    $("#registro_succes").show();       
                    $.fancybox.resize();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: your HTML is wrong. The ID must Be unique.

Comment: as @Arpit said, you made typo. first password1 should probably be usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Id must be unique**

change this line to

```
   <input id="usuario1" type="text" class="text" size="20" name="usuario">
```

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions :

1.Make ID of password1 unique.

```
<label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
<input id="password1" type="text" class="text" size="20" name="usuario">
           ^^^^^^^^^^    
<label for="contrasena">Contraseña</label>
<input id="password1" type="password" class="text" size="20" name="contrasena">
           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

1. Change else if

   ```
    if( password1 != password2 ){   // remove the else because both if checking different       things.    
       errors += '<p>error2</p>'; 
       }
   ```

Comment: That's right! I'm a fool, i didn't realize that i had the same id for user and password because i was focused looking the jquery script... thank you and sorry for wasting your time with such a silly thing.